# Create UFL to directly mail report as PDF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I need to create a User Function Library in C#, with Visual Studio 2010, that will allow someone viewing a Report in CR XI to directly send said report as an email.

I've never created a UFL, I've never worked with Crystal Reports, and I'm fully aware of just how incompatible the disparate versions are, how important it is to sort out precisely which one I'll be working with before being able to finalize any development.

What I need to know is...where do I even begin with this? I've seen a few questions similar to this, though most involve printing the report, rather than emailing it. I realize this is a bit remedial compared to the usual content of Stack, but I haven't much luck getting my feet under me, myself. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've got so far. Clicking the first button preps what clicking the second button is supposed to send, and yet nothing seems to happen throughout. I'm told that `System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail` is obsolete, but haven't found anything that works any better, either.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
    cryRpt.Load("CrystalReport1.cs");
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
        DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
        PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
        CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = pdfFile;
        CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;
        CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
        CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
        CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
        CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
        cryRpt.Export();

        sendmail();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void sendmail()
{
    try
    {
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0, "your hostname");
        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
        Msg.To = "to address here";
        Msg.From = "from address here";
        Msg.Subject = "Crystal Report Attachment ";
        Msg.Body = "Crystal Report Attachment ";
        Msg.Attachments.Add(new MailAttachment(pdfFile));
        System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(Msg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we're looking for something similar to this
http://www.crystalkeen.com/tools/mail.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this through both Outlook and smtp. If Outlook is *not* running, it will open an instance, send the email, then close. If it is already running, it will use the current instance to do the same, provided both the program and Outlook are running with the same level of privileges.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load("CrystalReport1.rpt");
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
    try
    {
        ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
        DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
        PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
        CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = pdfFile;
        CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;
        CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
        CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
        CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
        CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
        cryRpt.Export();
        sendmail();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void sendmail()
{
    Outlook.Application app = null;

    if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Length > 0)
    {
        app = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
    }
    else
    {
        app = new Outlook.Application();
    }

    try
    {
//In case of Outlook
        Outlook.TaskItem tsk = (Outlook.TaskItem)app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olTaskItem);
        Outlook.MailItem mail = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
        Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser = app.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;

        mail.Attachments.Add(pdfFile);
        mail.Subject = "This is the subject";
        mail.To = "destination@email.com";
        mail.Body = "mail with attachment";
        mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
        mail.Display(false);
        mail.Send();

//In case of smtp - This bit is a bit more temperamental. Suggestions for improvement are welcome.
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.Subject = "This is the subject";
        mail.From = new MailAddress(UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress);
        mail.To = "destination@email.com";
        mail.Body = "mail with attachment";
        Attachment attachment;
        attachment = new Attachment(pdfFile);
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient
        {
            "smtp.office365.com",
            Host = "outlook.office365.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@email.com", "Password")
            Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
            };

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

    public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application GetActiveOutlookApplication()
    {
        return (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else out.